# how to execute mvn commands from shell script

Tags: shell, maven, sh

I am writing a shell script(abcd.sh) and executing on windows 10.

```
mvn clean install
echo "TESTING"
```

When I am running it using

```
sh abcd.sh
```

then I am not getting any output in the screen. I am not sure the maven command is getting executed or not.
The second line is also never getting printed on the screen.

Comment: how are you running  a shell script on windows? by installing bash?

Comment: windows power shell supports shell

Comment: have you tried putting an echo before `mvn` line? Maybe, mvn path is not correctly set

Comment: echo is working fine when I am putting in first line. and mvn is working fine when running in power shell

Comment: just in case if you want Unix/Linux like terminal on windows: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194615/109344

Comment: (1) What do you see when you put a `set -x` in the first line? (2) What happens if you change the first line to `mvn clean install || echo TEST`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Windows 10 ,you can use bash.
To enable bash in Windows 10:

- Click the Start button , click Control Panel, click Programs, and then click Turn Windows features on or off.
- Enable Windows Subsystem for Linux(Beta)
- To get Bash installed, open Command Prompt and type “bash”. 
  [image]

Also , You can log the console output of maven commands in a text file and verify if the command was executed or not.

e.g.

```
mvn clean install --log-file output.txt
```